# United Kingdom transit visa for 4-5 days

Tags: uk, transit, transit-visas

I'm travelling from India to Canada and I have Canada visa with me. I haven't buy ticket yet. I want to stay 4 to 5 days in United Kingdom. And I'm planning to buy British Airways ticket which has 1 stop at LHR.

- Is there anything like that transit visa available?
- Can I apply for it?
- How much does it cost?

Answer (score 4):

The UK does issue a special category of [Visitor in Transit](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa) visas, but they are only for stays of at most 48 hours.

For a 4-5 day stopover you'll need to apply for a Standard Visitor visa, which costs £87.

(That's if you need a visa for the UK in the first place, of course -- I assume so, since otherwise you probably wouldn't have asked, but I don't *know* since you haven't told us your nationality).